# React component interaction and global state changes

Tags: javascript, state, reactjs

I'm very new to React, just experimenting with it. I'd like to know what are some common patterns, or libraries o built-ins for handling communication among components. For example, I have am input component and a "list" component that updates from the server according to what is in the input controller. Think of an autocomplete box. Since components have presentation logic, What if the two can't be "besides"? They're in different parts of the page and hence two different controllers.

Also, what if I have a login / logout button that works via Ajax? I imagine a lot of different components across the page reacting to the login / logout action reconfiguring themselves accord to a global "logged" state and the data retrieved from the server for the specific user that has logged in.

What is the best way that React "reacts" to those changes? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should checkout [Flux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYkdrAPrdcw) and [Dispatcher](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html).
It's kind of like a pub/sub system but without the problems of a pub/sub system. The advantage is that all events flow in one direction which makes the architecture much simpler and scalable.

Comment: Since the question is specifically for React, it's easier to look at an actual `Flux` implementation `redux` and `redux-react`.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you should checkout Facebook's official React documentation. They have a really thorough tutorial that covers 90% of the scenarios you'll run into, including best practices for component interaction. They're also really good about building from no knowledge on up. Only takes about 20 minutes to go through: https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html

As mentioned in another answer, Redux is an amazing library for handling app state and keeping components separate that shouldn't know about each other. Basically, you can have parent and child components, but if you ever have a component with over 2 levels of children, you should consider using Redux (or Flux) to handle state between unrelated components. The problem redux solves is just breaking up those dependencies and still allowing components to have a single source of truth. Their official documentation is also really good: http://redux.js.org/